# How to configure CorsRule for CDK using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I am trying to figure out the proper syntax for setting up cors on an s3 bucket using CDK (python). The class `aws_s3.CorsRule` requires 3 params (allowed_methods, allowed_origins, max_age=None). I am trying to specify the `allowed_methods` which takes in a list of methods but the bases is `enum.Enum`. So how do I create a list of these methods. This is what I have tried but it doesn't pass validation.

```
s3.Bucket(self, "StaticSiteBucket",
        bucket_name="replaceMeWithBucketName",
        versioned=True,
        removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
        website_index_document="index.html",
        cors=s3.CorsRule(allowed_methods=[s3.HttpMethods.DELETE],allowed_origins=["*"],max_age=3000)
        )
```

The only thing Im focused on is the cors line:

```
cors=s3.CorsRule(allowed_methods=[s3.HttpMethods.DELETE],allowed_origins=["*"],max_age=3000)
```

Trying to read the documentation is like peeling an onion.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3/HttpMethods.html#aws_cdk.aws_s3.HttpMethods

I tried calling each one individually as you can see using `s3.HttpMethods.DELETE` but that fails when it tries to synthesize.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you at least forgot to wrap the param you pass to `cors` as a list. I agree that the docs are a bit of a rabbit hole, but you can see the [Bucket docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3/Bucket.html) specifies the cors param as `(Optional[List[CorsRule]])`

This is mine:

```py
from aws_cdk import core
from aws_cdk import aws_s3
from aws_cdk import aws_apigateway

aws_s3.Bucket(self,
    'my_bucket',
    bucket_name='my_bucket',
    removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    cors=[aws_s3.CorsRule(
        allowed_headers=["*"],
        allowed_methods=[aws_s3.HttpMethods.PUT],
        allowed_origins=["*"])
    ])
```

So yours should be:

```
cors=[s3.CorsRule(
    allowed_methods=[s3.HttpMethods.DELETE],
    allowed_origins=["*"],
    max_age=3000)]
```